# Google Tango service outdated

Tags: android, google-project-tango

Try to launch Tango Java example "hello_motion_tracking" to my Lenovo phab2 pro phone. It always says "tango service outdated". My phone's system is already up to date. I also downloaded the latest Java example. How to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you device showed "tango service outdated." 
It means that your Tango Core need to be updated.

Please go to Play Store,
Search for "Tango Core" 
and updated it.

Just making sure your Tango Core is up to date, it will solve the problem.
Lasting Tango Core is Gankino release.
Please check release notes for more details.

https://developers.google.com/tango/release-notes